# Slim 3 not rendering assets

Tags: html, css, symfony, twig, slim-3

So I'm trying to render my global stylesheet but I am getting an error

> [Error] Did not parse stylesheet at 'http://localhost:8888/css/app.css' because non CSS MIME types are not allowed in strict mode.

Here is my code:

app.twig

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>App</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ base_url() }}/css/app.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

index.twig

```
{% extends 'app.twig' %}

{% block content %}
    Hello from {{ appName }}!
{% endblock %}
```

app.css

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

html, body {
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
  background: yellow;
}
```

As you can see in my structure the file is there [screenshot](https://gyazo.com/3b3a2c98a780e503198ee3797ea54e99)

I've been looking to resolve this issue but can't see to find the fix, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Prolly misconfigured webserver where the CSS mime is set to `text/plain` instead of `text/css`

Comment: @DarkBee I have tried

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ base_url() }}/css/app.css" type="text/css">

as well, still not working.

Also this is local not production.

Comment: Which webserver are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should configure your web server to parse and send the CSS file directly.

If you're using the built-in PHP web server, then add this to the top of index.php:

```
if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli-server') {
    $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = basename(__FILE__);
    // To help the built-in PHP dev server, check if the request was actually for
    // something which should probably be served as a static file
    $url  = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $file = __DIR__ . $url['path'];
    if (is_file($file)) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

If you're using Apache or Nginx, then look at https://www.slimframework.com/docs/start/web-servers.html